# Add values in excel between two specific dates and according to the value, positive or negative

Tags: excel, sum, conditional-statements

I need to create an excel workbook that would control incomes and outcomes of a store. In the first page we will write all transactions and dates. And the second page must totalize them according to the date in which they were caused.

Page 1:
[image: Page 1 of the workbook]

Page 2:
[image: Page 2 of the workbook]

So, the seccond page, on the cell B2 must show all the transactions that are positive in value (income) and that happend in that specific month (november). And the cell C2 must show all the transactions that are negative in value (outcome) of that same month, so cell C3 will be the gross profit: B2 - C2. And so one for every month...

Help!! Thank you!!

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: you could do it like in [THIS](http://superuser.com/questions/995541/how-do-i-merge-duplicate-cells-col-a-whilst-summing-their-values-in-col-c-whilst/997595#997595) example (using column F for your dates) an then use `COUNTIFS` for positive/negative values to get income/outcome